# What do I do if I can't find any key molds?

Tags: terraria-mobile

Can any one tell me how to get a key mold? I have been trying really hard but have never been able to find them.  What can I do?

Comment: The drop rate for key molds is *tiny* (1/2500 or 0.04%), you may simply be having some bad luck...

Answer (score -1):

I had some trouble getting key molds too. What I did was kill mobs and monsters for about 45 minutes straight and they COULD drop a key mold.